# Make bootstrap carousel move when hover on div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a nav which contains a list and currently when I hover on the last 3 list items, an image appears just below the list item(or tab). However, when each image appears it overlaps the bootstrap carousel just beneath the navbar. How do I make the bootstrap carousel move down so that it sits just below the image when the image appears on hover of each tab? Any answers would be helpful. 
see below code

```css
#nav{
  height: 5vw;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: gray;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#nav-ul li{
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 16%;
    position: relative;
}
#nav-ul li:not(:first-child){
    margin-left: 2%;
}
#nav-ul li a {
color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
}
#nav-ul{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
#nav-ul img{
display: block;
z-index: 1;
}
#li-1 img{
    margin-top: 2vw;
    position: absolute;
    height: 9vw;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#li-1:hover #li-img-1{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#li-2 img{
    margin-top: 2vw;
    position: absolute;
    height: 9vw;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#li-2:hover #li-img-2{
   display: block;
    margin-top: 0; 
}
#li-3 img{
  margin-top: 2vw;
    position: absolute;
    height: 9vw;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;   
}
#li-3:hover #li-img-3{
   display: block;
    margin-top: 0; 
}
#myCarousel{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 3vw;
}

.carousel-inner div{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 3vw;
}
.carousel-inner div p{
    line-height: 3vw;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
              <meta name="viewport" width="device-width" initial-scale="1.0">
            <title>Money CV</title>
            <link href="moneycv.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            </head>


<body>

<div id="nav">
              <ul id="nav-ul">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
                    <li id="li-1"><a href="#">Employee's Portal</a>
                     <img src="https://www.image.ie/images/no-image.png" id="li-img-1"/>
                    </li>
                    <li id="li-2"><a href="#">Services</a>
                     <img src="https://www.image.ie/images/no-image.png" id="li-img-2"/>
                    </li>
                    <li id="li-3"><a href="#">Organising</a>
                     <img src="https://www.image.ie/images/no-image.png" id="li-img-3"/>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
    <p>Testimonial 1</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <p>Testimonial 2</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
         <p>Testimonial 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

`